# ¿Existe un alt como en la etiqueta <img> que ofrezca el mismo resultado en un <li>?

Tags: html

Estoy haciendo una lista y querría informar al usuario que puede eliminar el elemento añadido a la lista haciendo click en dicho elemento. He pensado que al igual que el atributo alt informa con una frase en relación a una imagen, pudiera existir algo parecido que se pueda asociar a una `<li>` así cuando pase el usuario el cursor sobre los elementos que forman la lista aparezca un texto que le diga algo como 'Click para eliminar el elemento'.

Comment: Lo que buscas es el atributo [`title`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp)

Comment: Como indica Fly, el atributo que hace esa función se llama "title", el atributo que mencionas "alt" hace otra cosa en las imágenes, en caso de no ecnontrarse la imagen, se muestra en texto el contenido de "alt".

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas que no tratan sobre un error o problema en específico sino más bien como una duda ¿se podrían tratar mejor en el chat de SOes? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: Como bien dice @Fly, con `title` y un poco de CSS, podrás impresionar. [Mira aquí tres simples ejemplos](https://codepen.io/neogomo/pen/BjqJzr) como aperitivo de otras cosas que se pueden hacer. Y si te gustan los frameworks minimalistas, prueba `bulma`, [aquí varios ejemplos de tooltip](https://wikiki.github.io/elements/tooltip/).

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podrias crear algo asi:

```css
[data-title] {
  font-size:25px; 
  position: relative;
  cursor: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUGV0.png"), auto;
}

[data-title]:hover::before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -26px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
[data-title]:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  border: 8px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Mi Lista</h1>
<ul>
  <li data-title="Click para eliminar">Opcion 2</li>
</ul>
```

Esto es usando el atributo **data**, ahora bien también podrias hacerlo de la forma clasica sin estilos ni nada:

```html
<ul>
 <li title="Click para eliminar">Opcion 1</li>
</ul>
```

usando el atributo **title** como ya te habian comentado, espero te sirva como base y te guie..!!